# Finding volume of a region in Multi-Variable Calculus

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I converted both functions into polar form and got $z = r$ and $z = r^2 - r\cos\theta$. So I get the integrands as $[r^2]drd\theta$ and $[r^3 - r^2 \cos\theta] drd\theta$ but now I'm having difficulty visualizing the shapes and setting the bounds on $r$ and $\theta$. I assume $\theta$ is from $0$ to $2π$ (correct me if I'm wrong) - but I still don't completely understand why this is the case. Also, I'm having trouble setting up $r$ bounds. When I choose $0<r<2$  I get a different volume for the cylinder than $2<r<4$ and none of them equal $$V= \pi r^2h= 4\pi(4) = 16\pi.$$ Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - no, that's not the correct equation for the cylinder. There's no $z$ in the cylinder's equation; it should be $(r\cos\theta-2)^2+(r\sin\theta)^2 = 4$, or $r^2-4r\cos\theta = 0$. We're interested in the inside, which would be $r^2-4r\cos\theta \le 0$. The other two bounding surfaces are $z=r$ as you found and $z=0$, for $0\le z\le r$.

Second - no, $\theta$ is not from zero to $2\pi$. Look at the picture; the cylinder is entirely on one side of the $y$ axis. That's only half of the angle range around the origin, for $\theta$ between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Putting these pieces together, the integral becomes
$$V = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_?^? (r-0)\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta$$
Yeah, we still need those $r$ bounds. That comes from the cylinder. Solving $r^2\le 4r\cos\theta$ for $r$, we get (since $r$ is always nonnegative) that $0\le r\le 4\cos\theta$. Now we finally have the integral completely set up:
$$V = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{4\cos\theta} r\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I solved the equation for the cylinder up to the point of [cylinder function] = 0 but I mistakenly substituted z instead for 0 after that. Regarding the r bounds, why isn't it just 0 to 2 or 2 to 4 since the base of the cylinder is a circle so r should go from center to outer edge of the base?

Comment: The base of the cylinder is a circle, but it's not a circle centered at the origin of the coordinate system we're using. An equation "$r=c$" represents a circle centered at the origin, and the equation of a circle centered elsewhere looks different in polar coordinates. This is at least the second nicest case, a circle that passes through the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Why use (shifted) radial coordinates when rectilinear are so easy?

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^4 \int\limits_{y = -\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2}}^{\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2}} \int\limits_{z=0}^{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} 1\ dx\ dy\ dz = \frac{256}{9} \neq 16 \pi.$$

[image]

Comment: What software did you use to get this graph?

Comment: *Mathematica*...